# Face Recognizer using EigenObjectRecognizer

Tags: c#, emgucv

```
 Image<Gray, Byte>[] trainingImages = new Image<Gray,Byte>[5];  

 trainingImages[0] = new Image<Gray, byte>("MyPic.jpg");

 String[] labels = new String[] { "mine"}

  MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(1, 0.001);

 EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
       trainingImages,
       labels,
       1000,
       ref termCrit);

        Image<Gray,Byte> testImage = new Image<Gray,Byte>("sample_photo.jpg");

     var result= recognizer.Recognize(testImage);
```

result.label always returns string "mine"(label of the training image) for every face it detects.
result.label must be the returned when the detected faces are same in the two images, instead it returns same label for every face.

What is the problem with my code.